# An expression of non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected, near in sql server

Tags: java, sql-server

I get the below Exception when i run the query:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ROW_NUM_VAL, CASE WHEN ingest_table.[OVER]_RAN  BETWEEN '10' AND '12' THEN 'F' ELSE 'P' END [OVER]_STATUS FROM(SELECT [OVER] AS [OVER]_RAN FROM S_3000_7_vt)ingest_table)rgtt WHERE [OVER]_STATUS = 'F'
```

exception:

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: An expression of
>   non-boolean type specified in a context where a condition is expected,
>   near '_RAN'.

How can i solve this?

Comment: I'm not sure how Java is involved here besides you obviously executing the query via JDBC. Other than that, I'd assume that `[OVER]_RAN` is the problem. I don't know SQL Server that well so I don't know what `[OVER]` is meant to mean but I'd assume it doesn't do what you expect.

Comment: Another thing that might be a problem: I'd say there's a comma missing between `END` and `[OVER]_STATUS` in `... ELSE 'P' END [OVER]_STATUS FROM ...`. Did you try to execute that query directly on the database, i.e. by using some native client?

Comment: sql server has a keyword OVER clause, so in this query `SELECT [OVER] AS [OVER]_RAN FROM S_3000_7_vt`, OVER is the column name of table, if i give SELECT OVER AS OVER_RAN FROM S_3000_7_vt) it is treating OVER as clause @Thomas

Comment: Well that's what I suspected but I'd probably opt for a different name rather than hard to read and thus error prone column names such as `[OVER]_RAN` or even `[OVER]`.

Comment: i have solved it, posted answer @Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it this way:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ROW_NUM_VAL, CASE WHEN ingest_table.OVER_RAN  BETWEEN '10' AND '12' THEN 'F' ELSE 'P' END OVER_STATUS FROM(SELECT [OVER] AS OVER_RAN FROM S_3000_7_vt)ingest_table)rgtt WHERE OVER_STATUS = 'F'
```

keeping the column as [OVER], just changed the alias name from [OVER]_STATUS TO OVER_STATUS,[OVER]_RAN TO OVER_RAN

Answer (score 0):

You miss `,` after `CASE ... END` state, and `[OVER]_STATUS` from where.

Change it to

```
SELECT * 
FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0)) AS ROW_NUM_VAL, 
         CASE 
             WHEN ingest_table.[OVER]_RAN  BETWEEN '10' AND '12' 
                  THEN 'F' 
         ELSE 'P' END, 
         [OVER]_STATUS -- ??????
  FROM 
         (
           SELECT [OVER] AS [OVER]_RAN 
           FROM S_3000_7_vt
         )ingest_table  -- do not have [OVER]_STATUS
  )rgtt
 WHERE [OVER]_STATUS = 'F'
```